# Question on epsilon-delta definition of limits (several variable)

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity, epsilon-delta

I have the following question before me:

q. Use epsilon − delta definition to show that f(x, y) = [(x^3) + (y^3)] is continuous at (0,0).

i started with:

epsilon > 0 and mod(x^3 + y^3) < epsilon

how do i proceed after this?

Comment: Hint: Convert to polar coordinates: $x^3 + y^3 = r^3(\cos^3\theta + \sin^3\theta)$, then $|x^3 + y^3| =|r^3(\cos^3\theta + \sin^3\theta)|< 2r^3.$

Comment: thank you, but i have to solve this in x-y coordinate only, is there any way to do that?

Comment: You can just substitute $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, $\cos\theta = x/r$, $\sin\theta = y/r$ and have everything in terms of $x$ and $y$

Comment: got it, thank you so much